# How Change Color of specifics Vertex in JUNG

Tags: java, graph, colors, jung

I'm trying change the color of the Vertex, but just some of them, I need 3 diferents colors in the screen, somebody know how to do that?
I'm making like that:

```
Transformer<V, Paint> vertexPaintRed = new Transformer<V, Paint>() {
    public Paint transform(V input) {
         return Color.red;
    }
};
```

But with it I just can change the color of all Vertex. and I wanna change the color of some of them, The ones that only have edges getting out I need one color, the others that have edges just arriving I need other color, and the rest I need another color. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to write something like

```
Transformer<V, Paint> vertexPaintRed = new Transformer<V, Paint>() {
    public Paint transform(V input) {
         if (hasOnlyOutgoingEdges(input)) return Color.RED;
         if (hasOnlyIncomingEdges(input)) return Color.GREEN;
         return Color.BLUE;
    }
};
```

with an appropriate implementation of the methods checking the type of the vertex.

For example, if you know the JUNG `Graph` that contains the vertex, at the place where the Transformer is created, you could simply write

```
Transformer<V, Paint> vertexPaintRed = new Transformer<V, Paint>() {
    public Paint transform(V input) {
         if (jungGraph.inDegree(input) == 0) return Color.RED;
         if (jungGraph.outDegree(input) == 0) return Color.GREEN;
         return Color.BLUE;
    }
};
```